# How to import a json object with objloader (three js) using react and express js

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, three.js

Im trying to import a large `.json` model to my project using [threejs OBJLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader),
but it seems that my server is replacing the `.json` model with my main HTML file , noticed when it try to parse and gives the error:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tried by calling the model with a simple require() inside my js file, and shows:

> TypeError: url.lastIndexOf is not a function

Also tried by using stringify in the required model and shows:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

there is the `threejs` error object:

```
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
lengthComputable: false
loaded: 0
path: []
returnValue: true
srcElement: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
target: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
timeStamp: 1096.5999999898486
total: 0
type: "error"
__proto__: ProgressEvent
```

this is my js file where I'm trying to load the model

```
const THREE = require ('three');
const obj1 = require('../img/orig.json');
const orig = JSON.stringify(obj1);


export default canvas =>{
    const info = document.getElementById('three_origami');
    let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 ),
    scene = new THREE.Scene(), renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    let group=new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    let mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
    let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    let windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
    init();
    animate();
    function init() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
        camera.position.z = 40;
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
        scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xfffff, 1, 10000 );

        group = new THREE.Group();

        const objLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();


        objLoader.load(orig, (obj) => {
                for ( let i = 0; i <= 300; i ++ ) {
                    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( obj.geometry, obj.material );
                    mesh.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                    mesh.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                    mesh.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                    mesh.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                    mesh.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                    mesh.updateMatrix();
                    group.add(mesh);
                }
            },
            null,
            (err) => {
              console.error('Error', err);
            });

        scene.add( group );
        //
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        info.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        //
        //
        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        //
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
    }
    function onWindowResize() {
        windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    }
    function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
        mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) * 10;
        mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * 10;
    }
    //
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();
    }
    function render() {
        let time = Date.now() * 0.001;
        let rx = Math.sin( time * 0.7 ) * 0.5,
            ry = Math.sin( time * 0.3 ) * 0.5,
            rz = Math.sin( time * 0.2 ) * 0.5;
        camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
        camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
        camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        group.rotation.x = rx;
        group.rotation.y = ry;
        group.rotation.z = rz;
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
}
```

This is the .json file in my repository: [portfolio-final/orig.json](https://github.com/gabvrel/portfolio-final/blob/master/src/img/orig.json)

and my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "portfolio-final",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^5.0.3",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "gsap": "^2.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.0.6",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.1.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^6.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "three": "^0.97.0",
    "url-loader": "1.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.9",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.2",
    "xhr": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "start-dev": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn run build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node",
      "xhr"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The reason why you're getting the `Unexpected token` is that your server can't find that file so it returns a 404 page. Three.js is trying to parse a website as a JSON file.

By default when you require a JSON file Webpack includes it in the bundle at build time. At runtime it will just return the JSON object not the path to the file because there is no JSON file, it's in the bundle with all the other Javascript.

So basically `require ('../img/orig.json');` returns the JSON object.

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) turns a JSON object into a string, which is not what we're looking for.

You could make Webpack not include the JSON file into the bundle, placing the file in the destination folder and requiring it would return the path, using [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/). But there is an easier way.

[`ObjectLoader.load`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader.parse) takes a URL to the JSON file *but* [`ObjectLoader.parse`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader.parse) takes a JSON object which is exactly what we're looking for

You can bundle the json using `require ('../img/orig.json');` and then use [`ObjectLoader.parse`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader.parse) to parse the json:

```
const THREE = require ('three');
const orig = require ('../img/orig.json');



export default canvas =>{
    const info = document.getElementById('three_origami');
    let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 ),
    scene = new THREE.Scene(), renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    let group=new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    let mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
    let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    let windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
            init();
            animate();
            function init() {
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 40;
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xfffff, 1, 10000 );

                group = new THREE.Group();


                    const objLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();


                    objLoader.parse(orig, (obj) => {
                        for ( let i = 0; i <= 300; i ++ ) {
                            let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( obj.geometry, obj.material );
                            mesh.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                            mesh.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                            mesh.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                            mesh.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                            mesh.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                            mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                            mesh.updateMatrix();
                            group.add(mesh);
                        }
                    });

                scene.add( group );
                //
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                info.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                //
                //
                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                //
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            }
            function onWindowResize() {
                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }
            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) * 10;
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * 10;
            }
            //
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
            }
            function render() {
                let time = Date.now() * 0.001;
                let rx = Math.sin( time * 0.7 ) * 0.5,
                    ry = Math.sin( time * 0.3 ) * 0.5,
                    rz = Math.sin( time * 0.2 ) * 0.5;
                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                group.rotation.x = rx;
                group.rotation.y = ry;
                group.rotation.z = rz;
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
}



const THREE = require ('three');
const orig = require ('../img/orig.json');



export default canvas =>{
    const info = document.getElementById('three_origami');
    let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 ),
    scene = new THREE.Scene(), renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    let group=new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    let mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
    let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    let windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
            init();
            animate();
            function init() {
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 40;
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xfffff, 1, 10000 );

                group = new THREE.Group();


                    const objLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();


                    objLoader.parse(orig, (obj) => {
                        for ( let i = 0; i <= 300; i ++ ) {
                            let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( obj.geometry, obj.material );
                            mesh.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                            mesh.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                            mesh.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                            mesh.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                            mesh.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                            mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                            mesh.updateMatrix();
                            group.add(mesh);
                        }
                    });

                scene.add( group );
                //
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                info.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                //
                //
                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                //
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            }
            function onWindowResize() {
                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }
            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) * 10;
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * 10;
            }
            //
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
            }
            function render() {
                let time = Date.now() * 0.001;
                let rx = Math.sin( time * 0.7 ) * 0.5,
                    ry = Math.sin( time * 0.3 ) * 0.5,
                    rz = Math.sin( time * 0.2 ) * 0.5;
                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                group.rotation.x = rx;
                group.rotation.y = ry;
                group.rotation.z = rz;
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
}
```

I changed the `objLoader.load('/dist/orig.json')` to `objLoader.parse(orig)` and remove the `JSON.stringify`.

Hopefully, this works for you.

Comment: `When you require a JSON file Webpack includes it in the bundle at build time` Is this true? What if the JSON is gineormous, 100x or 1000x times larger than your application?

Comment: I tested with a 1.31 MB JSON file. That appears to be the case. You can use the file-loader to get the URL.

Comment: Also, I edited the post to Include why you're getting the `Unexpected token` in the first place

Comment: You configure webpack to handle files with various loaders. It's up to you to decide when and if JSON gets inlined.

Comment: `When you require a JSON file Webpack includes it in the bundle at build time.` This is not true in generic sense. It depends on the OPs webpack configuration. It may also return a path...

Comment: @pailhead Yes, that is true but by default (Or at least since 3.0), Webpack includes it in the bundle. That's why I talk about the file-loader just to show that there are other options and that Webpack is configurable. But I'll edit the post to remove confusion